# Fortran multidimensional sub-array performance

Tags: performance, multidimensional-array, fortran

While manipulating and assigning sub-arrays within multidimensional arrays in Fortran90, I stumbled across an interesting performance quirk.

Fortran90 introduced the ability to manipulate sub-sections of arrays and I have seen a few places which recommends that array operations be performed using this "slicing" method instead of loops. For instance, if I have to add two arrays, `a` and `b` of size 10, it is better to write:

`c(1:10) = a(1:10) + b(1:10)`

or

`c = a + b`

Instead of

```
do i = 1, 10
    c(i) = a(i) + b(i)
end do
```

I tried this method for simple one dimensional and two dimensional arrays and found it to be faster with the "slicing" notation. However, things began to get a little interesting when assigning such results within multidimensional arrays.

First of all, I must apologize for my rather crude performance measuring exercise. I am not even sure if the method I have adopted is the right way to time and test codes, but I am fairly confident about the qualitative results of the test.

```
program main
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: mSize = 10000
    integer :: i, j
    integer :: pCnt, nCnt, cntRt, cntMx
    integer, dimension(mSize, mSize) :: a, b
    integer, dimension(mSize, mSize, 3) :: c

    pCnt = 0
    call SYSTEM_CLOCK(nCnt, cntRt, cntMx)
    print *, "First call: ", nCnt-pCnt
    pCnt = nCnt

    do j = 1, mSize
        do i = 1, mSize
            a(i, j) = i*j
            b(i, j) = i+j
        end do
    end do

    call SYSTEM_CLOCK(nCnt, cntRt, cntMx)
    print *, "Created Matrices: ", nCnt-pCnt
    pCnt = nCnt

    ! OPERATIONS BY SLICING NOTATION
    !c(1:mSize, 1:mSize, 1) = a + b
    !c(1:mSize, 1:mSize, 2) = a - b
    !c(1:mSize, 1:mSize, 3) = a * b

    ! OPERATIONS WITH LOOP
    do j = 1, mSize
        do i = 1, mSize
            c(i, j, 1) = a(i, j) + b(i, j)
            c(i, j, 2) = a(i, j) - b(i, j)
            c(i, j, 3) = a(i, j) * b(i, j)
        end do
    end do

    call SYSTEM_CLOCK(nCnt, cntRt, cntMx)
    print *, "Added Matrices: ", nCnt-pCnt
    pCnt = nCnt
end program main
```

As can be seen, I have two methods of operating upon and assigning two large 2D arrays into a 3D array. I was heavily in favour of using the slicing notation as it helped me write shorter and more elegant looking code. But upon observing how severely sluggish my code was, I was forced to recheck the capacity of slicing notation over calculating within loops.

I ran the above code with and without -O3 flag using GNU Fortran 4.8.4 for Ubuntu 14.04

1. Without -O3 flag

   a. Slicing notation

   ```
        5 Runs - 843, 842, 842, 841, 859

        Average - 845.4
   ```

   b. Looped calculation

   ```
        5 Runs - 1713, 1713, 1723, 1711, 1713

        Average - 1714.6
   ```
2. With -O3 flag

   a. Slicing notation

   ```
        5 Runs - 545, 545, 544, 544, 548

        Average - 545.2
   ```

   b. Looped calculation

   ```
        5 Runs - 479, 477, 475, 472, 472

        Average - 475
   ```

I found it very interesting that without -O3 flag, the slicing notation continued to perform way better than loops. However, using -O3 flag causes this advantage to vanish completely. Contrarily, it becomes detrimental to use array slicing notation in this case.

In fact, with my rather large 3D parallel computation code, this is turning out to be a significant bottle-neck. I strongly suspect that the formation of array temporaries during the assignment of a lower dimensional array to a higher dimensional array is the culprit here. But why did the optimization flag fail to optimize the assignment in this case?

Moreover, I feel that blaming -O3 flag is not a respectable thing to do. So are array temporaries really the culprit? Is there something else I may be missing? Any insight will be extremely helpful in speeding up my code. Thanks!

Comment: Could you use a more recent version of gfortran?

Comment: Look at the options `-O3` implies.  The compiler can do aggressive loop unrolling if you ask and this might be what you are seeing (e.g. your looping case isnt a loop anymore).

Comment: I don't think the compiler needs to make array temporaries in this case.

Comment: Also, you should initialize your variables and print the result. Otherwise, my gfortran just reports that the second part takes 0 ms because it optimized it away or moved before the time check.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I could use a newer version of gfortran, but in the end, I will have to submit the code to my college cluster whose fortran version is not really in my control. I first observed this speed difference on the cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing any performance comparison, you have to compare apple with apples and orange with oranges. What I mean is that you are not really comparing the same thing. They are totally different even if they are producing the same result.

What comes into play here is the memory management, think of cache faults during the operation. If you turn the loop version into 3 different loops as suggested by haraldkl you will certainly get similar performance.

What happens is that when you combine the 3 assignments in the same loop, there is a lot of cache reuse for right hand side since all the 3 share the same variables in the right hand side. Each element of `a` or `b` is loaded into the cache and into registers only once for the loop version while for the array operation version, each element of `a` or `b` gets loaded 3 times. That is what makes the difference. The larger the size of the array, the larger the difference, because you will get more cache fault and more reloading of elements into the registers.

Comment: @haraldkl, well, that is my explanation, it might not be complete.

Comment: @ VladimirF, althought I am not sure that my explanation fit all the cases, I suspect that you have a computer with very large cache, and then you are not getting a lot of cache fault.

Comment: it is a very reasonable explanation, and I totally agree, it's just that theoretically the compiler could even optimize the array syntax version and collapse the loops. In my experience this is unlikely, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the compiler really does so not really an answer, but too much text for a comment...
I'd have the suspicion that the compiler expands the array notation into something like this:

```
do j = 1, mSize
    do i = 1, mSize
        c(i, j, 1) = a(i, j) + b(i, j)
    end do
end do
do j = 1, mSize
    do i = 1, mSize
        c(i, j, 2) = a(i, j) - b(i, j)
    end do
end do
do j = 1, mSize
    do i = 1, mSize
        c(i, j, 3) = a(i, j) * b(i, j)
    end do
end do
```

Of course, the compiler might still collapse these loops if written like that, so you might need to confuse him a little more, for example by writing something of c to the screen between the loops.

Comment: With ifort14 -O3, both the colon and loop versions seem to be running equally fast, so the compiler may have fused the above three loops into a single one. I have also tried "cheating" by inserting print *, c(1,1,1) between the first and second loop etc, then there was a significant speed down... :)